# C Strings of Unequal Length, Lowercase to Uppercase

Tags: c, cstring, uppercase, lowercase, string-conversion

I'm trying to implement a function that receives a c string as input, converts all lowercase characters to uppercase, then stores the result in the output parameter. Here is the code for this function:

```
void makeUpper( const unsigned char* input, unsigned char* output ) 
{

    int inputLength = strlen((char*)input);
    int outputLength = strlen((char*)output);

    for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
    {
        if ((input[i] >= 97) && (input[i] <= 122))
        {
            output[i] = input[i] - 32;
        }
        else
        {
            output[i] = input[i];
        }
    }

}
```

Now, a problem will clearly arise in the case that inputLength > outputLength. To remedy this, I inserted a the following code between the inputLength & outputLength declarations and for loop.

```
if (inputLength > outputLength)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (inputLength - outputLength); i++)
    {
        strcat((char*)output, " ");
    }
}
```

Not only is this producing an error (this function or variable may be unsafe...), but I'm almost certain that I'm going about this the wrong way. However, I cannot think of any alternatives.

EDIT:

The main function I am using is as follows:

```
int main() 
{

  unsigned char in[] = "HELLO aaaaaaaaaa 678";
  unsigned char out[] = "                    xxxxxxxxx";

  makeUpper( in, out );
  cout << in << " -> " << out << endl;
  makeUpper( out, in );
  cout << out << " -> " << in << endl;

 return 0;

}
```

What I the function should print is:

```
HELLO aaaaaaaaaa 678 -> HELLO AAAAAAAAAA 678xxxxxxxxx
HELLO AAAAAAAAAA 678xxxxxxxxx -> HELLO AAAAAAAAAA 678XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Is the buffer supposed to be passed in by consumers of the function, or can you `malloc` the buffer yourself?

Comment: @IanMcLaird: `strncat()` is as lethal as `strcat()`, primarily because you have to know how much data is already stored in the target string to be able to specify the length correctly, but if you know that, you barely need to use a `*cat()` function at all.

Comment: You either need to assume that there's enough space in the target string (simpler) or you have to pass the length of the target string to the function as an argument.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you're absolutely right, and I've deleted my earlier comment (I hope) before anybody takes it as good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the "present contents of the output parameter" with "available space". The former is irrelevant, and the only information you have about the latter is "there is at least this much space available".

Now it will depend on how the space for `output` was assigned in the first place. If you did something like

```
char output[100];
strcpy(output, "hello");
```

You would end up with space for 100 characters, but only 6 (5+1) actually used. You could therefore take the string "ThiS IS a STRING" and process it with your function, without problem.

But this is not safe, because you don't know how much space there is.  The following approach would be better:

```
char *output;
output = malloc(100);
```

Now change your function prototype to

```
void makeUpper( const unsigned char* input, unsigned char** output )
```

and in your function, you do

```
inputLength = strlen(input);
*output = realloc(*output, inputLength + 1);
```

This will make sure that enough space is allocated for the output. Or you could return the value in the input vector - you already *know* there is enough space there...

**EDIT** In the example you give, there is enough space in the `output`; the question simply becomes one of "safely copying" the (uppercased) input to the output.  In which case your function can look like this:

```
void makeUpper( const unsigned char* input, unsigned char* output ) 
{

    int inputLength = strlen(input);
    int outputLength = strlen(output);
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < inputLength; ii++)
    {
        output[ii] = toupper(input[ii]);
    }
    if(outputLength < inputLength) output[ii] = '\0';
}
```

The final line is there to make sure that if you increased the length of `output` (again, assuming this was memory you could validly access), then you still need to make sure there's a terminating `nul` character at the end of the string. In your example, you want the "rest of the output string" to still be there when the `input` is shorter than the `output`, so you need the `if` condition.

In general - if you do not know for sure that `output` is big enough, there is no way to make it bigger without having access to the address of the pointer - sometimes called the "handle".

Comment: Any way to do this without altering the prototype?

Comment: Another question, when I run the program everything prints correctly, however, an error is produced: "Stack around the variable 'in' was corrupted." Is this because more characters are being stored in in[] than were originally allocated?

Comment: When you make the second call and copy `out` back to `in`, you are indeed exceeding the available space in `in`, and may end up overwriting parts of `out` (Although what gets corrupted depends on how the compiler chooses to allocate the stack - there are no fixed rules). So yes - "don't do it"!

Answer (score 0):

If the output buffer can be assumed to be created within the function:

```
// C++ version
void makeUpper(const unsigned char* input, unsigned char*& output)
{
    // assume output = null
    int inputLength = strlen((const char*)input);
    output = new unsigned char[inputLength + 1];
    memset(output, 0, inputLength + 1); // initialize the array to 0's

    for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
    {
        output[i] = ::toupper(input[i]); // why reinvent the wheel
    }
}

// C version
void makeUpper(const unsigned char* input, unsigned char** output) 
{
    // assume output = null
    int inputLength = strlen((const char*)input);
    *output = (unsigned char*)malloc((inputLength + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    memset(*output, 0, (inputLength + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char)); // initialize the array to 0's

    for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
    {
        (*output)[i] = ::toupper(input[i]);
    }
}
```

`output` would need to be deleted/freed by whoever takes control of it.

If you do not want to properly size `output` inside the function:

```
void makeUpper(const unsigned char* input, unsigned char* output, unsigned int output_size) 
{
    // assume output != null, the current contents of output are irrelevant - you need it's size
    int inputLength = strlen((const char*)input);
    int maxLength = (inputLength < output_size - 1 ? inputLength : output_size - 1);
    memset(output, 0, output_size); // clear output

    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        output[i] = ::toupper(input[i]); // why reinvent the wheel
    }
}
```

NOTE:  The C++ tag was removed while I was writing my answer.  This really only affects the first solution (as you would use `malloc` instead of `new`).  I would shy away from `realloc` or `calloc` unless your requirements absolutely necessitate them.

Comment: You can't use references in a C solution either - affecting your first solution a little more.

Comment: Hence the double-pointer comment below it.  For clarity, I split it up into a C++ and C version.